# Is there a way to play a video on Android without interrupting external audio?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I need to display a video (which contains no audio track) but playing that video using `VideoView`or `MediaPlayer` automatically interrupts any ongoing audio playback which may be currently active in another application.

My requirements are to:

- play a video which contains no audio track
- do not interfere with any ongoing audio playback

Is there a way to play such a video without hijacking the audio channel?

Comment: Related - [click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995176/android-google-music-app-stops-when-my-intro-video-plays)