# when playing video in splash screen the music playing in background pauses

Tags: android

when playing video in splash screen the music playing in background pauses, the splash screen doesn't have any audio and i dont want the audio or music playing in background to stop or pause.
 this is what i'm doing

video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.splash_screen_video));
video.setOnCompletionListener(completionListener);
video.start();

can someone please suggest of how to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I found (personally, I do not recommend it) is copy VideoView class from Android sources and comment out these lines:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

Finally I opted for [ruxy solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995176/android-google-music-app-stops-when-my-intro-video-plays)