# Playing Webm in Videoview without gaining audio focus

Tags: android

I currently have an app which plays numerous animated gifs in .webm format. However, as I have this in a videoview, it gains audio focus, therefore other apps playing audio will stop.

Is there any work around to prevent this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I found (personally, I do not recommend it) is copy VideoView class from Android sources and comment out these lines:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

Finally I opted for [ruxy solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995176/android-google-music-app-stops-when-my-intro-video-plays) but probably will not be an option in your case

Comment: Thanks, Ana. In the end I ended up putting a MediaPlayer on a SurfaceView. Unfortunately it meant I had to make my own Media Controller, as you can only attach them to Video Views, but does sort my problem out. (an example can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700587/how-to-attach-mediaplayer-with-surfaceview-in-android)